# Div with "display: none" style appears anyway

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with the id "hubspot-contact-form". This div has a display style of none. But when the page loads, the div appears anyway. Can anyone help me figure out how to hide this form when the page loads? Here is the whole page. Thanks.

```
<?php

    include ('includes/secure.php');
    include ('includes/globals.php');
    $thisPage = "contact";

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<?php include ('includes/pageTitle.php') ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/browserDetect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer")
{
    document.write("<link href='css/stylesIE.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
} else {
    document.write("<link href='css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
}
// -->
</script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

function show(id)
{
     if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none')
     {
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
     }
}

function hide(id)
{
          document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';

}

</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"><!--

function validateForm() {
with (document.contactForm) {
var alertMsg = "The following REQUIRED fields\nhave been left empty:\n";
if (name.value == "") alertMsg += "\nYour Name";
if (email.value == "") alertMsg += "\nEmail Address";
checkemail = email.value
AtPos = checkemail.indexOf("@")
StopPos = checkemail.lastIndexOf(".")

if (AtPos == -1 || StopPos == -1) {
    alertMsg += "\nProvide a Valid Email Address";
}
if (subject.options[subject.selectedIndex].value == "") alertMsg += "\nSubject";
if (comments.value == "") alertMsg += "\nMessage/Comments";
if (alertMsg != "The following REQUIRED fields\nhave been left empty:\n") {
alert(alertMsg);
return false;
} else {
return true;
} } }

// --></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="site">

<DIV ID="dek"></DIV>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--

//Pop up information box II (Mike McGrath (mike_mcgrath@lineone.net,  http://website.lineone.net/~mike_mcgrath))
//Permission granted to Dynamicdrive.com to include script in archive
//For this and 100's more DHTML scripts, visit http://dynamicdrive.com

Xoffset=-60;    // modify these values to ...
Yoffset= 20;    // change the popup position.

var old,skn,iex=(document.all),yyy=-1000;

var ns4=document.layers
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
var ie4=document.all

if (ns4)
skn=document.dek
else if (ns6)
skn=document.getElementById("dek").style
else if (ie4)
skn=document.all.dek.style
if(ns4)document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
else{
skn.visibility="visible"
skn.display="none"
}
document.onmousemove=get_mouse;

function popup(msg,bak){
var content="<TABLE WIDTH=250 BORDER=0 class='infoBox'><TD ALIGN=left class='infoBoxText'>"+msg+"</TD></TABLE>";
yyy=Yoffset;
 if(ns4){skn.document.write(content);skn.document.close();skn.visibility="visible"}
 if(ns6){document.getElementById("dek").innerHTML=content;skn.display=''}
 if(ie4){document.all("dek").innerHTML=content;skn.display=''}
}

function get_mouse(e){
var x=(ns4||ns6)?e.pageX:event.x+document.body.scrollLeft;
skn.left=x+Xoffset;
var y=(ns4||ns6)?e.pageY:event.y+document.body.scrollTop;
skn.top=y+yyy;
}

function kill(){
yyy=-1000;
if(ns4){skn.visibility="hidden";}
else if (ns6||ie4)
skn.display="none"
}

//-->
</SCRIPT>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <?php include ('includes/header.php') ?>
    </div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="500" class="showborder">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" width="619">
                <img src="images/contactTITLE.gif" border="0" alt="Contact AOP"><br />
                <div id="scrollBorder">
                <div id="boxScroll">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="598">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top" class="text">
                                <?php showStatus($_REQUEST['status']) ?>
                                <?php include ('includes/pageContent.php') ?>
                                <br><br>
                    <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */
                       HubSpotFormSpamCheck_LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0 = function() {
                           var key = document.getElementById('LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_key').value;
                           var sig = '';
                           for (var x = 0; x< key.length; x++ ) {
                                    sig += key.charCodeAt(x)+13;
                           }
                           document.getElementById('LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_sig').value = sig;
                           // Set the hidden field to contain the user token
                           var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?hubspotutk=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
                            if (results && results[2]) {
                                document.getElementById('LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0submitter_user_token').value =  results[2];
                            } else if (window['hsut']) {
                                document.getElementById('LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0submitter_user_token').value = window['hsut'];
                            }
                            return true;
                       };

                      showContactForm = function() {
//debugger;
                        var formDiv = document.getElementById('hubspot-contact-form');
                        var formType = document.getElementById('subject').value;

                        if(formType == 'General Feedback' || formType == 'General Patent Study' || formType == 'Specific Patent Study') {
                          formDiv.style.display = 'block';
                          } else {
                            //formDiv.innerHTML = '';
                          }
                        }
                    /*]]>*/</script>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            * Subject:<br><br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="10"></td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <select name="subject" id="subject" class="field">
                                                <?php if ($_REQUEST['subject'] != "") { ?>
                                                    <?=$_REQUEST['subject']?>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
                                                <option value="General Feedback" onclick="showContactForm()">General Feedback</option>
                                                <option value="Website/Technical" onclick="showContactForm()">Website/Technical</option>
                                                <option value="General Patent Study" onclick="showContactForm()">General Patent Study</option>
                                                <option value="Specific Patent Study" onclick="showContactForm()">Specific Patent Study</option>
                                                <option value="Profit Sharing" onclick="showContactForm()">Profit Sharing</option>
                                            </select><br><br>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                <div id="hubspot-contact-form" style="display: none;">
                   <form action="http://info.articleonepartners.com/Default.aspx?app=iframeform&hidemenu=true&ContactFormID=29555" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="FormSubmitRedirectURL" id="FormSubmitRedirectURL" value="http://www.articleonepartners.com/contact.php?status=contact_request_has_been_sent" >
                      <input type="hidden" name="Lead_Src" id="LeadSrc" value="Contact Us" />
                      <input type="hidden" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0submitter_user_token" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0submitter_user_token"  value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="ContactFormId"  value="" />
                      <input type="hidden" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_key" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_key"  value="hjdrmdpfjkflkpjigdjonkqqpjinqssqr" />
                      <input type="hidden" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_sig" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0spam_check_sig"  value="" />
                      <div class='ContactFormItems FormClassID_29555'>
                        <table border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="showborder">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right">First Name <span style="color: red"> *</span><br /><br /></td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="Text" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0:FirstName" class="field StandardI AutoFormInput LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_AutoForm" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_FirstName" value="" /><br /><br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right">Last Name <span style="color: red"> *</span><br /><br /></td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="Text" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0:LastName" class="field StandardI AutoFormInput LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_AutoForm" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_LastName" value="" /><br /><br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right">Email (we will keep your email completely private) <span style="color: red"> *</span></td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="Text" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0:Email" class="field StandardI AutoFormInput LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_AutoForm" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_Email" value="" /><br /><br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right">Phone (optional)<br /><br /></td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="Text" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0:Phone" class="field StandardI AutoFormInput LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_AutoForm" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_Phone" value="" /><br /><br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="top">Please Enter Your Message: <span style="color: red"> *</span><br /><br /></td>
                            <td width="40"></td>
                            <td align="left"><textarea type="Text" cols="40" rows="6" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0:Message" class="StandardI AutoFormInput LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_AutoForm" id="LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0_Message"  ></textarea><br /><br /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr><td></td><td width="40"></td><td><input onclick="return HubSpotFormSpamCheck_LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0();" class="FormSubmitButton" type="submit" name="LeadGen_ContactForm_Submit_LeadGen_ContactForm_29555_m0" value="Submit"></td></tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <img src="images/patentCatButtons.gif" width="617" height="32" border="0" alt="" usemap="#patentCatButtons_Map"><br />
                <map name="patentCatButtons_Map">
                <area shape="rect" alt="Full List" coords="496,0,617,32" href="list.php">
                <area shape="rect" alt="Patent Study Results" coords="295,0,496,32" href="patent_study_results.php">
                <area shape="rect" alt="Technology" coords="147,0,295,31" href="list.php?category=Technology">
                <area shape="rect" alt="Healthcare" coords="0,0,147,32" href="list.php?category=Healthcare">
                </map>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="15"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                            <?php include ('includes/mainNav.php') ?>

                            <div id="homeText">
                                <img src="images/homeText.png" border="0"><br />
                            </div>

                            <?php include ('includes/searchBox.php') ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                            <?php include ('includes/news2.php') ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="footerLong">
        <div id="footerTextLeft">
            <span onmouseover="show('copyright');return true;" onmouseout="hide('copyright');return true;">&copy; <?=date("Y")?>    ARTICLE ONE PARTNERS, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span><br />
            <div id="copyright" style="DISPLAY: none">
                The content contained on this site is provided to users "AS IS" without any express or implied warranty.<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include ('includes/footer.php') ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The div looks o.k. as far as I can see. Is this valid HTML code? Can you run it through the validator to exclude the possibility of overlapping DIVs?

Comment: Honestly, I am not going to read through this extensive code sample. You really should consider trying to isolate the problem to the least possible amount of code. Then update your question if it hasn't sorted itself out during that process.

Comment: You'd be able to write this JavaScript in a tenth of the LoC if you used something like jQuery...

Comment: Why not use jQuery's show/hide for this (`$('#'+id).hide();`)? You are including the library anyway.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers or only IE?  Can you simplify and still have the error occur? (i.e. remove everything except the form and simplify the CSS to just those id's etc that are in the form)  You have included all of the html but none of the CSS. Might something in the CSS be overriding something you have done inline?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `div` starts inside a `table` structure. This is not valid and guaranteed to mess up the rendering result:

```
   </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- No-no! Either end the table or start a new table row. -->
   <div id="hubspot-contact-form" style="display: none;">
```

It is likely that the `div` gets ignored, and the following `tr`s get merrily rendered, even if they are supposed to be hidden. You need to fix the HTML first.

You need to integrate the DIV into the table somehow, either by introducing another table, or using [`tbody`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_tbody.asp) elements.

Always be sure to run your HTML through the [**validator**](http://validator.w3.org/) when hunting for display bugs.

Comment: Nice catch! I didnt notice that. It looks like he meant to but is missing the opening <tr> and <td> because he closes them below the div. Unless those are different ones. I cant tell

Comment: Actually it is worse. The closing `tr` before the `div` is nested inside a `td` which is not legal anyway.

Comment: @Turismo Yeah, there are some more quirks in there. Valid HTML is the first step to recovery. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm pretty sure this is the problem, although I didn't get a chance to test it because my boss took a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're missing opening tr and td tags just prior to the div.  Try adding those in and see if that fixes the problem.